# Dynamically set out type in Expression Func

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Starting with the following:

```
        string propertyName = TextBoxPropertyToGet.Text;
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "x");
        Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);
        Expression<Func<Item, string>> expression = (Expression<Func<Item, string>>)lambda;
```

What I was hoping to do:

```
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "x");
        PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Item).GetProperty(propertyName);
        Type pt = pi.PropertyType;
        Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, pi);
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);
        Expression<Func<Item, pt>> expression = (Expression<Func<Item, pt>>)lambda;
```

but I get the error: 
`The type or namespace name 'pt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` On the last line.

I don't want to use:

```
if(pt == typeof(string))
    Expression<Func<Item, string>>....
else if(pt==typeof(decimal))
    Expression<Func<Item, decimal>>....
....
....
```

I have also tried:

```
var expression = Expression.Lambda(
                 Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(
                 arg, propertyName),
                 pt), 
                 arg);
```

AND

```
var lambdaMethodParamType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Item), pt);
var expression = typeof(Expression).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Lambda" && x.IsGenericMethod).MakeGenericMethod(lambdaMethodParamType);
```

but then I get: 
`The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

basically telling me to do what I don't want to do.

I have tried (as proposed by Servy)

```
string propertyName = TextBoxPropertyToGet.Text;;
ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "x");
Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);

var x = Queryable.Select(MyContext.Items,(dynamic)lambda);
```

but this returns empty, and when trying to call  `var x = Queryable.Select(MyContext.Items,(dynamic)lambda).Distinct();` I get the error `'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `Select` using reflection, rather than calling it normally, if the generic arguments are not known at compile time.  This means getting the `Type` of `Queryable`, getting the `Select` method, choosing the right overload, etc.

The alternative is to use `dynamic`, which does pretty much the same thing, but handles generating pretty much of that dynamic typing for you:

```
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);
dynamic query = Queryable.Select(data, (dynamic)lambda);
```

Comment: I got 'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyClass.Item>' has no applicable method named 'Select' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.`

Comment: @user2125348 So then follow the error message's advice and call the extension method without the extension method syntax, as it suggests.

Comment: Don't know how. I'm still trying to learn how all this works.

Comment: I tried it as `Queryable.Select(query, (dynamic)lambda)` instead of `query.Select((dynamic)lambda))` but while it doesn't error it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @user2125348 It can't return nothing.  The language is not designed to allow nothing to be returned.  Do you mean it returns `null`?  If so, `Select` won't ever return `null`.  If you mean it returns an empty query, then you should first be checking to ensure that your query represents something that will return results even without this select, because it won't affect the number of items in the result set.

Comment: It returns empty, the code in my question following Starting with the following, works as expected and does return data. but when I use the code you have shown it returns empty.

Comment: Also of note, when I try to also use query.distinct() it throws another error `'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct'` I don't think this way of coding is going to work for my needs.

Comment: If that's the type, then you have clearly not called `Select` on it, so you're doing something wrong.  If you don't want to do this, then, as I described, you're welcome to do it all using reflection.  It'll take a screens worth of code to handle it all, but you can do it.  Those are pretty much your only two options if you don't know the type of the projected value though.

Comment: I have updated my answer with what I have tried if you are still interested in maybe seeing what I have done wrong.

Comment: Thank you anyways for the effort you did provide it is greatly appreciated!